# Flip the model instance through controller return to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

- I created a model, I created instances of the model in the controller
- I want to send this instance data to partial view (does not work)

**Model**

```
 public partial class userDaty_Model
    {
        public int liczbaDniM { get; set; }

        public int numerMiesiacaM { get; set; }

        public int numerRokuM { get; set; }
    }



// which is part of ParentView


public partial class ParentView
    {
        public userDaty_Model Model4 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Ajax code in main view from which I am calling partialView.**

```
 var userDate = {
             numerMiesiaca: $("#id_sb_month").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value"),
             numerRoku: $("#id_sb_year").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value"),
             liczbaDni: liczbaDni
         };


        $.ajax({

            url: "@Url.Action("PartialTabelaEcp", "Home")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"userDate": JSON.stringify(userDate)},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#kartaEcp").html(data);
            },
            failure: function (error) {
                alert(error);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string userDate)
        {
int liczbaDni =2;
int numerMiesiaca = 6;
int numerRoku = 12;

userDaty_Model userDaty = new userDaty_Model();
            userDaty.liczbaDniM = liczbaDni;
            userDaty.numerRokuM = numerMiesiaca;
            userDaty.numerMiesiacaM = numerRoku;


// return, which returns the view
 return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/_TabelaEwidencja.cshtml");

// return who I want to return but gives me nothing
 return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/_TabelaEwidencja.cshtml", userDaty );
}


***edit
 I changed and I have "return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja", userDaty);"and it is still the same as it was
```

I set the red dot to return, when there is no instance of the 'userDate' model it goes through return

When it's in
Error

> jquery.js:9837 POST https://localhost:44362/Home/PartialTabelaEcp 500 (Internal Server Error)

after :
Error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

**partialView**

```
@model ParentView


// ...
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: a 500 error indicates that an error was thrown on the server side (in your `PartialTabelaEcp` controller action). surround the code inside the controller action with a try/catch block and set a breakpoint in the catch section. Run your code, find what the exception is then fix it yourself or report back here and we'll be of more help to you. also it doesnt look liek the model you return in your action matches the expected model in your partial view and you shouldnt need to specify the entire path to the partial view

Comment: @GregH I update, I set the red dot to return, when there is no instance of the 'userDate' model it goes through return, When it's in Error
jquery.js:9837 POST https://localhost:44362/Home/PartialTabelaEcp 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: then it sounds like your error is during the compilation of the razor view which would indicate your passing teh wrong model to your partial view or have some other issue with you partial view. you should be able to override `OnException` in your controller (there are tons of examples on how to do this) and set a breakpoint in there to find the actual error. you gave me the error message from the client side which isn't what you need to find. you need to find where it's failing server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like below:

1.Ajax(change from `dataType:"json"` to `dataType:"html"`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("PartialTabelaEcp", "Home")",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",   
    data: {"userDate": JSON.stringify(userDate)},
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#kartaEcp").html(data);
    }
});
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialTabelaEcp(string userDate)
{
    int liczbaDni = 2;
    int numerMiesiaca = 6;
    int numerRoku = 12;

    userDaty_Model userDaty = new userDaty_Model();
    userDaty.liczbaDniM = liczbaDni;
    userDaty.numerRokuM = numerMiesiaca;
    userDaty.numerMiesiacaM = numerRoku;

    var data = new ParentView()
    {
        Model4 = userDaty
    };
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_TabelaEwidencja.cshtml", data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the right model in your @model if you give him the Daty model but say him it is a Parent View Model it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can't return full paths to views, views are always relative to a folder inside the Views folder and the name of the controller (this can be changed, of course), like, for example:

```
/Views/Home
/Views/Admin
```

So, you should be calling instead:

```
return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja", userDaty);
```

Also, in your view, declare the right type of model: either `userDaty_Model` or `dynamic`, this is using the `@model` keyword.

Comment: I changed and I have "return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja", userDaty);"and it is still the same as it was